# MYSQL - IF column contains character THEN ... ELSE

Tags: mysql

I have a column `product_id` that can contain an underscore.If it does,i want to grab everything to the left of it,like so:

```
 SELECT LEFT(product_id,LOCATE('_',product_id) - 1) As po, product_id FROM orders_item
```

This produces the following:

```
po     product_id   
40     40_59
46     46_74
95     95_223
134    134_271
86     86_265
71
76
48     48_79
137    137_298
50     50_247
48     48_80
124    124_187
```

However it ignores any records that don't have an underscore.How do I write the following in MySQL?

```
 If `<contains underscore>` THEN `<everything to the left of the underscore>` ELSE `<entire field>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_id, '_', 1) AS po, product_id
FROM orders_item
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, will accept when the timer allows! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` for that:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('_', product_id) > 0 THEN LEFT(product_id, LOCATE('_', product_id) - 1)
        ELSE product_id
    END AS po,
    product_id
FROM
    orders_item
```